# Mesh shading is split in half

Tags: modeling, faces

Im not sure how to put this, but the faces are flipped on one part om my mesh.
Is there any other way of correcting them without doing it manually?
Recalculate doesnt work.
[image: The faces..]

Comment: What you mean by "doing it manually"? Run the flip normal operator? So the problem is to select only a portion of the model? Could you clarify?

Comment: By manually i mean all the faces that are wrong and flipping them. Is there any other option to correctly flip them ?

Comment: If it fails to recalculate them correctly, it means your mesh doesn't have a clean topology, so inside and outside can't be properly defined. Maybe 3 faces sharing an edge somewhere. The cloth part perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In edit mode, select every face below the collar that you want to flip and press W > Flip Normals.